# Moving file/files from remote directory to another Spring Integration SFTP Outbound Gateway Java Config/Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

In my project, I am able to list files, get them, process them, and now I need to move the remote files to a new directory, but I am having issues using the mv command. I use [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#using-the-mv-command) as reference.

My code

```
    @MessagingGateway
    public interface SftpMessagingGateway {
        @Gateway(requestChannel = "listFiles")
        List<File> readListOfFiles(String payload);

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "getFiles")
        List<File> getFiles(String payload);

        @Gateway(requestChannel = "moveFiles")
        void backupFiles(List<File> payload);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser(username);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "listFiles")
    public MessageHandler sftpReadHandler(){
        return new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "'/oldDirectory/'");
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "moveFiles")
    public MessageHandler sftpPutHandler(){
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mv", "'/oldDirectory/'"+ "+ headers['file_relativePath']" );
        sftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("'/newDirectory/'"+ "+ headers['file_relativePath']"));
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "getFiles")
    public MessageHandler sftpGetHandler(){
        SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mget", "'/oldDirectory/'");
        sftpOutboundGateway.setLocalDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"));
        sftpOutboundGateway.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        return sftpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

where I am calling this in a service: `sftpGateway.backupFiles(files)`
where I want to move all processed files from "'/oldDirectory/'" to "'/newDirectory/'"
I am getting an error: `"error occurred in message handler [bean 'sftpPutHandler'; defined in: 'class path resource [SFTPConfig.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@1654a892']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to delete file /newDirectory/null; nested exception is 2: No such file"`

I have tried changing the payload and the rename expression, but I dont think I am getting to the point where I am able to run this command on each file in oldDirectory or move all files at once from old directory to the new directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that with your `void backupFiles(List<File> payload);` gateway contract you don't satisfy an SFTP mv expectations. You have this a couple expressions which are bases on the `headers['file_relativePath']`, but there is just no such a header when gateway method call is sending a message.

However I still don't see how is that going to work: you send a list of files and you don't split that list before calling SFTP mv.

Or use `splitter` to deal with a single file on the SFTP gateway. Or have a `@Gateway` contract as a single file and call it in the list iterator.

You probably can just rename `oldDirectory` to a `newDirectory` having all the remote content relocated respectively. But I'm not sure if that is what you want to achieve...

Comment: I have changed the gateway:
```@Gateway(requestChannel = "putFiles")
        void backupFiles(File payload);```
and calling it by:
```
File[] files = new File("sftp-inbound").listFiles();
Arrays.stream(files).forEach(sftpGateway::backupFiles);
```
I am getting an error `/newDirectory/null; nested exception is 2: No such file`

Comment: OK. Do you provide that `file_relativePath` header also? Your expressions are evaluated to `null` because there is no such an info supplied in the message from the `@Gateway`

Comment: thats probably it. How do I provide the header/filename?

Comment: You can add it as a `@Header` argument to the `@Gateway` contract or just rely on the `payload` which is `File` object with respective name. See more info about gateway in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gateway.html#gateway